# Mocking High Volume Portal User , Required fields are missing: [ProfileId]

Tags: unit-test, community

Apex testmethod to create High Volume Portal Users

```
// mock User(s) to create SObjects
...
// insert Account(s) and Contact(s)
...
system.runAs(someUser) {
  insert new List<User> {   new User (
                                        Alias               = '_' + 'user00'+'_',
                                        ContactId           = someContactid,                        
                                        Email               = '_user00@bar.com',
                                        EmailEncodingKey    = 'UTF-8',
                                        FirstName           = '_fname',
                                        IsActive            = true,
                                        LanguageLocaleKey   = 'en_US',
                                        LastName            = '_' + 'user00' + '_lname',
                                        LocaleSidKey        = 'en_US',
                                        ProfileId           = someProfileIdthatIsNonNull,
                                        UserName            = '_' + 'user00' + '_foo@bar.com',
                                        TimeZoneSidKey      = 'America/Los_Angeles'
                                                ) };
```

- `someContactId` is valid, was mocked earlier
- The Account(s) were created with a user that has a `userRoleId != null`
- `someProfileIdThatIsNonNull` is a valid `ProfileId` for a Community Community License

> Yet, this error ensues on insert.....

```
REQUIRED_FIELD_MISSING, Required fields are missing: [ProfileId]: [ProfileId]
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

*(This cost me an hour of time to figure out, posting to save others that time)*

First of all, the answer is not `isTest (seeAllData=true)`

### Here's the solution ...

Even though the `User.ProfileId` value is non-null and valid (proven through debug statements), **if the running user doesn't have permissions to create Users**, you get this error. Had I gotten an error indicating that the running user didn't have CRUD permissions on `User` this wouldn't have merited a question or answer. But the required fields error is detected first before the insert and hence the confusion.

An easy trap to fall into when your mind is focused on the special nuances around HVP users and writing testmethods to verify your custom community logic.

Basically, I was trying to mock data where the `someUser` represented the Community Manager but I didn't mock that user correctly.

Creating SObjects and setup data in a testmethod frequently runs into `MIXED_DML` error wherein you need to use `System.runAs(...)` around your SObject creation before the `Test.startTest()`. Hence, be sure your running User has permissions to create the necessary Sobjects.

Comment: Wait, your `someUser` isn't `someAdmin`? I always insert `User` records as `System Administrator`.

Comment: @AdrianLarson - as I said, the use case was simulating a Community Manager who had delegated admin privileges and I forgot about that in the mocking.  So, yes, `face plant` --your mind goes into thinking your `profileId` is wrong or there is something unique about Communities or the `contactId` isn't set up right or anything but the now, obvious.